# Логи релизного билд

Tags: android, логирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, инструмент, который может писать логи в текстовый файл (или еще что-нибудь) на устройстве, чтобы этот файл можно было открыть и прочитать.
Правда есть пара нюансов:

- нужно, чтобы писались не только собственное логи, но и ошибки (краши)
- приложение обфусцировано и в LogCat'е и ничего не понятно. как с этим бороться?

Comment: Firebase как вариант, пишете лог, потом non-fatal exception и все это вместе появится в консоли. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вам подойдет Log4j ([можно взять отсюда](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.mindpipe.android/android-logging-log4j)). По умолчанию библиотека добавляет на каждый лог название класса откуда сделан вывод (запись ведется во внутреннюю память, каждый день новый файл). Для перехвата ANR можно использовать
[ANRWatchDog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog) , а для крашей добавить `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` в Application класс. Да, соответственно, чтобы избежать обфускации названия классов к логам добавляем название ручками, иначе никак (вариант выключить proguard я не рассматриваю ;)